# Multiple textTabs for a signer in a docusign request

Tags: docusignapi

When I am adding textTabs element in my docusign request, I am getting text tabs got created in the document goes to signer, but when signer types info in one tab, it get filled in another tab as well.

I want signer to insert different values in different text tabs.

Here is textTabs element in my request for a signer-

```
<tabs>
   <textTabs>
        <text>
            <anchorString>\11ba\</anchorString>
            <tabOrder>1</tabOrder>
            <width>100</width>
            <height>33</height>
            <shared>false</shared>
        </text>
        <text>
            <anchorString>\abcd\</anchorString>
            <tabOrder>2</tabOrder>
            <width>150</width>
            <height>50</height>
            <shared>false</shared>
        </text>
    </textTabs>
</tabs>
```

Any suggestion pls ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a feature, not a bug.

If you have two or more tabs in a document with the same label (parameter `tabLabel`) then, when the signer fills in one, the other(s) will get the same value.

Since you don't want that behavior, set the `tabLabel` values for each tab, and set them to be different from each other.

Comment: Thanks Larry. This is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Glad to help @trilok -- please "check" (accept) my answer so I can get some points.

Answer (score 1):

As Larry has mentioned you need to provide unique/different `tabLabel` values for each of the two tabs.  For example:

```
<tabs>
   <textTabs>
        <text>
            <tabLabel>FirstTabName</tabLabel>
            <anchorString>\11ba\</anchorString>
            <tabOrder>1</tabOrder>
            <width>100</width>
            <height>33</height>
            <shared>false</shared>
        </text>
        <text>
            <tabLabel>SecondTabName</tabLabel>
            <anchorString>\abcd\</anchorString>
            <tabOrder>2</tabOrder>
            <width>150</width>
            <height>50</height>
            <shared>false</shared>
        </text>
    </textTabs>
</tabs>
```